# Use the xsl:value-of content in the apply-templates query

Tags: xslt-1.0

Here is a small snippet of XSL script:

```
  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="border: thin solid #000000">
        <xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$History/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name='xxxx']"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

See:

```
<xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
```

? I want to use that value instead of the literal `'xxxx'` value in the `apply-templates` call.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer your question without seeing the overall context.

Technically, you could do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$History/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Name=current()/msa:Name]"/>
```

However, it's very likely that using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** would provide a better solution to the problem.